# Query to return in BSON document from an embedded collection in MongoDB using C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core, bson

I have an embedded collection in MongoDB like this :

```
{
   "Earth":
         {
            "Asia":
                 {
                    "India":
                          {
                             "Capital" : "New Delhi",
                             "Language " :"Hindi"
                          },

                    "Japan":
                          {
                              "Capital":"Tokyo",
                              "Language": "Japanese"
                          },

                    "China":
                          {
                              "Capital":"Beijing",
                              "Language": "Chinese"
                          }
                 }
         }  
 }
```

The country name is given as user input & I've to display that country information, for eg:, if the input given is India, the output should be :

```
         {
             "capital": "New Delhi",
             "language", "Hindi"
         }
```

How to retrieve this from MongoDB to a BSON document using C#?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe consider this:

```
internal class Country
{
  public string Continent { get; set; }
  public string Capital { get; set; }
  public string Language { get; set; }
}
```

Create your Countries and put them in a list:

```
private static IEnumerable<BsonDocument> CreateCountries()
  {
    var India = new BsonDocument
    {
      {"Continent", "Asia"},
      {"Capital", "New Delhi"},
      {"Language", "Hindi"}
    };

    var Japan = new BsonDocument
    {
      {"Continent", "Asia"},
      {"Capital", "Tokyo"},
      {"Language", "Japanese"}
    };

    var China = new BsonDocument
    {
      {"Continent", "Asia"},
      {"Capital", "Beijing"},
      {"Language", "Chinese"}
    };

    var newEarth = new List<BsonDocument>();
    newEarth.Add(India);
    newEarth.Add(Japan);
    newEarth.Add(China);

    return newEarth;
  }
}
```

This way you can accept input for India search the List and return any information associated with India. For more help with this you can go [HERE](https://www.codementor.io/pmbanugo/working-with-mongodb-in-net-part-3-skip-sort-limit-and-projections-oqfwncyka)